# profile scan codes for chat application

Tags: messenger, wechat, snapchat, kik, scannable-code

I was wondering where I could find more information about the various scan code protocols that recent chat applications are offering as an easy way to connect for their users. In particular, are there any open source libraries allowing a 3rd-party mobile app to scan these codes on both Android and iOS devices?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some introspection inside the Android messenger app from FB, I concluded that the code is proprietary and located in the package `com.facebook.messaging.imagecode` which relies on native code inside the `libfbmessengercodesjni.so` library. So unless facebook decided to open-source this library, it will take a lot of reverse engineering to get there.